# Updating field by previous record field value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to update date field from previous record date field in the same table, for exemple :

```
ID_1   ID_2                  start_date                   end_date   
  1     33          2017-12-14 10:28:32.203000              null
  1     33          2017-12-13 10:28:29.153000              null    
  1     33          2017-12-12 10:28:25.246000              null    
  1     33          2017-12-11 10:28:21.917000              null    
  2      4          2017-12-10 10:28:18.005000              null    
  2      4          2017-12-09 10:28:14.145000              null    
  2      4          2017-12-08 13:24:26.964834              null
```

I want to update end_date field by the previous start_date value in recods who have same ID_1 and ID_2. For exemple :

```
   ID_1  ID_2                start_date                   end_date   
    2      4            2017-12-08 13:24:26.964834     2017-12-09 10:28:14.145000
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a good case for the LAG or LEAD function. I will let someone else who is proficient in postgresql give you a solid answer.

Comment: I'm sure that you'll get an answer on how to do this, but once you do consider whether or not you actually want to do it. You're basically introducing duplicate data in your database, which is likely to cause lots of other issues in the future. Rather than adding duplicate data you should consider how you can use the existing data to do whatever you need in your application (or create a view that generates the data in a form that is useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres you can do:

```
update t
    set end_date = tn.next_start_date
    from (select t.*,
                 lead(start_date) over (partition by id_1, id_2 order by start_date) as next_start_date
          from t
         ) tn
    where tn.id_1 = t.id_1 and tn.id_2 = t.id_2 and tn.start_date = t.start_date
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon Linoff, but it seems that there is syntax error in your query, I'm not sure but I guess that "SET" is missing after "update t" and "SELECT" also missing before " from (select t.*,"

Comment: I have this error message : [42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t" , the *"from"* after *"set end_date = tn.next_start_date"* seems make trouble

Comment: @MK-rou . . . That is where your table name goes.